# Convert Lon/Lat degrees to X/Y coordinates in unity3d using c#

Tags: c#, gps, unity-game-engine, data-conversion, mathematical-expressions

I need to place 3d models at gps lat/lon degree coordinates which correspond with unity x/y coordinates and for that I need to convert the gps data , i.e, latitude and longitude in degrees to x, y coordinates in unity for my project in Augmented reality using Vuforia. Can someone help me with a C# script which handles the conversion without compromising precision?

Answer (score 1):

As shown on [this Unity Forum post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/923182/lat-long-to-unity-world-coordinates.html) you can convert Lat/Lon to X/Y with the following code:

```
public float latitude;
public float longitude;
Vector3 xyz_vector = Quaternion.AngleAxis(longitude, -Vector3.up) * Quaternion.AngleAxis(latitude, -Vector3.right) * new Vector3(0,0,1);
```

Comment: Okay i will try that. Thanks